# Querysets "lost" when I render them in the template

Tags: django, django-templates, python-3.2

I was stucked the last two days with this problem. First part of the code:

viewa.py

```
def A_dashboard(request):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    users = User.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', {"user": user, "users": users} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The dashboard will be different depending of one property of the user.
dashboard.html

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_A %}
        {% include "dashboards/A_dashboard.html" %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if user.is_B %}
        {% include "dashboards/B_dashboard.html" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

The concrete dashboard to the A user.

dashboards/A_dashboard.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<div class="offrow rowpadding dashboard-info">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <div class="row">
                    {{user}}
                    {{users}}
                    {% for user_ in users %}
                        <p>{{user_}}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                            {% include 'calendar.html' %}
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Right Now Im logged in as an A user. In the view I check the class to check that everything is ok. Its of class `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`

However, when I try to iterate the list in the template, it doesn't exist.

Can you imagine whats happening?

Regards.

Comment: Is any of these conditions (if user.is_A , if user.is_B) True ? .. i.e. Just wanted to know If the control reaches to include statements ?

Comment: Yes, they are true. I tried to take outside the code of A_dashboad inside the main dashboard and nothing happens too :)

Comment: Shot in the dark: Does adding whitespace around the variable names help? (e.g. `{{user_}}` -> `{{ user_ }}`)

Comment: there maybe 2 cases:
1. 'users' query set is empty: Check for the values in queryset in view itself first
2. Check all the context variables in the Template with tag {% debug %}. See if 'users' in in there

Comment: In the view queryset is full of data. I will try the second step

Comment: Its not been shown, however in the view it's visible.... CRAP

Comment: @PabloFlores what if putting the content of A_dashboard.html into if sentence?

Comment: The same problem. It's not shown. And debug is not showing the "users" query :S... It makes no sense.

Comment: I'm completely stucked. Any other ideas :S

Answer (score 0):

it is strange that objects don't exist.

`User.objects.all()` is queryset, so in template `users` is a queryset.

`user` is a user object, it has some attributes, such as `username` , `email` and so on.

`for user_ in users` you get every user object(`user_`) similar to `user` above

so try this

```
<div class="row">
    name： {{ user.username }}
    {% for user_ in users %}
        <p>name: {{ user_.username }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

`{{user.username}}` and `{{ user.username }}` are the same, spaces just for looking elegant

Comment: but when I test in django 1.6, it works, download my test project:http://www.rxnfinder.org/media/mysite.zip